# How to compare the two different positions in the file in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, file-pointer

I am implementing the program to zip a file using a run-length encoding compression method. Are there any ways you can compare the characters in the file or compare two file pointers to do that?

I opened the file(zipfilename) that I want to zip and set the file pointer named ftozip to it. Then, I tried to count the number of each character using this file pointer as shown in the code below (if condition).

```
FILE *ftozip;
ftozip = fopen(argv[1],"r");//open the file that we are zipping
if (ftozip == NULL) {//if there is an error opening
    perror("File cannot be opened ");
}
char zipfilename[30];
strcat(zipfilename, argv[1]);
strcat(zipfilename,".zip");
FILE *zipfilep = fopen(zipfilename, "a"); //zipfile openned to write

int count = 1;
while(1){ //incrementing the characters and storing in the zip  file
    if(*ftozip == *(ftozip +1)) {
        count++;
        char countchar[] = (char)count+(*ftozip);
        fputs(countchar, zipfilep);
        ftozip++;
        continue;
    }
    else {
        count = 1;
        countchar = (char)count + (*ftozip);
        ftozip++;
        if (feop(ftozip){
                break;
            }
            continue;
            }
    }
```

That resulting in this error "invalid operands to binary == (have ‘FILE’ and ‘FILE’)".

Comment: You probably want to read more about how to work with files in C. You need to use `fread`, `fseek`, etc. to work with `FILE*`.

Comment: You should exit the program after reporting the `fopen()` error, not continue to use the null file handle.

Comment: `char zipfilename[30]; strcat(zipfilename, argv[1]);` . Ooops.  strcat assumes `zipfilename` is a null terminated array, but at this point it is uninitialized.  You must not pass an uninitialized value as the first argument of `strcat`.

Comment: `char countchar[] = (char)count+(*ftozip)` :: Please go back to Java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dereferencing a pointer of type `FILE*`, as you do with `if(*ftozip == *(ftozip +1) ...`, does not access the contents of the file. 
To read or write from or to a file bytewise, use `fread` and `fwrite` instead.